# Parsing a python dictionary in bash shell

Tags: python, json, shell

```
$ query_op=$(ssh -p 29418 myreview-server.com gerrit query --files --current-patch-set --format=JSON --commit-message change:99934 | head -n 1 | python -c "import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)['currentPatchSet']['files']")
$ echo $query_op
[{u'deletions': 0, u'insertions': 11, u'type': u'ADDED', u'file': u'/COMMIT_MSG'}, {u'deletions': 0, u'insertions': 2, u'type': u'MODIFIED', u'file': u'foo/bar/baz/info.txt'}]
```

How do I find if any of the `file` starts with string `foo`? in the above shown example, I need to do some operation as there is a file starting with `foo/` which is `foo/bar/baz/info.txt`, if no file starts with `foo/` in the entire dictionary value, then I need to do different operation.

Comment: Why not do the parsing in your little block of Python? `any(x['file'].startswith('foo') for x in ...)` would do it (where `...` is the expression you're currently printing).

Comment: it did work, thank you.

Comment: @Blckknght, Can you please add it as a solution, I will accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As I commented, you can modify your Python one-liner to do the checking for a `foo` prefix, rather than printing out the whole dictionary. It is very easy to change it so that Python prints `True` or `False`, just wrap your current `json.loads` call with a generator expression and `any`:

```
any(x['file'].startswith('foo') for x in json.load(sys.stdin)['currentPatchSet']['files'])
```

Another option that might make it even easier to handle the output in the surrounding bash script would be to use `sys.exit` in Python to send the result as the Python interepreter's exit code, rather than as text sent to standard output. Conveniently, Python's `bool` data type is a subclass of `int` (with `True` equal to `1` and `False` equal to `0`), so you can pass the result of the `any` call in the code above directly to `sys.exit` instead of `print`ing it. Traditionally an exit code of `0` means success, while `1` means failure, so you may want `sys.exit(not any(...))`.